# Pycharm:how to change and save file in root?

Tags: pycharm

I got a file which is root privilege to edit. And I want to edit and then save(in Pycharm,it is called upload)it. I had configured both remote ssh in `Tools` and `Python Interpreter` for my remote. Also I add root priviledge by selecting `Execute code using this interpreter with root priviledges via sudo`. But it's still not able to upload my edits. What should I do?

Comment: This don't solve the problem but maybe it is an option to change the file privilege by using `chmod 755 your_file` so you do not need root.

Comment: @kabr8 Seems that is the only choice. Both Pycharm and VScode are not able to edit directly.